# Trying to make a DLL of my lib and getting unresolved external symbol __tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I have added my declspecs to my classes and all. I basically created a new DLL project and added all of my lib's files. It builds fine except for that unresolved external symbol. Why would I need a main for a DLL?

The error is:

> Error 84  error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol *main referenced in
>   function
>   _*_tmainCRTStartup    MSVCRTD.lib

My other 'errors' are warnings because I use std::vector a lot, but my std::vectors are protected.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a DLLMain function (check the reference for it on MSDN) which you might have to provide. In addition, you may have just set the project settings wrong and the linker may be expecting to create an exe.